# VS 2010 Premium : Navigating into Windows directories in a 64-bit project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, 64-bit

VS 2010 Premium :
I have a project which targets x86 platforms and I need to make it target x64 platforms.
I went to the Configuration Manager and from there to the Active Solution Platform, chose "new",added an 'x64' option and copied the settings from a Win32 platform (It's the only option I had).

So now the project should be targeting x64 platforms, if I'm not mistaken.

I have a code line in my project which asks for the file with this path : 
Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\ACEDAO.dll

Yet it seems that during compilation, this file is being requested from the "Common Files" directory within the Program Files(x86) directory (the one for 32-bit). Naturally the compilation fails, since no such file exists in this path.

How can I make it to navigate to the (Program Files\Common Files ..) directory ? 
The project should be targeting 64-bit after all and I require the 64-bit version of this dll.

Comment: Did you try removing and readding the reference to the library?

Comment: What is VS 2010 Premium?

Comment: Do you mean rewriting the same code line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binary produced by the compiler and linker is indeed a 64-bit image.  The compiler however is not, that's the one that reads the file so it is subject to file system redirection.  The default 64-bit compiler is the one in the vc\bin\x86_amd64 directory.  It is a 32-bit compiler that produces 64-bit code.  You could select vc\bin\amd64 in the project's VC++ Directories setting  to select the 64-bit compiler.

Something wrong with your machine setup though, I have this file present in `c:\program files (x86)`.  Windows 7 x64, Office 2010, VS2010.  I have no clue why you don't have it, you could ask at superuser.com.  Just copying the file is a simple workaround.  Also beware that the 64-bit version of the ACE provider is not distributable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I removed the specific file from the x86 directory because I wanted to test it on with the 64-bit version of the file and I think they can not be installed at the same time.

Comment: Well, don't do that.  You're using the type library, the bitness doesn't matter.  And they *can* be installed at the same time, the registration keys for 32-bit COM servers are kept in another part of the registry.

Comment: Regarding your answer, could you tell me exactly what to change in the VC++ directories ? 
I should go to "Executable directories", right ?
And then change the "$(VCInstallDir)bin\x86_amd64" value ? to what then ?

Comment: Don't do this, put the file back.  Ask another question if you don't know what "type library" means.

Comment: Well, my task is basically running this project on a x64 platform and causing it to navigate into the x64 Windows directories by default .. the part with the dll is less important .. The important thing is that the file path I posted in my original post currently navigates to the x86 directory and it's not what I wish for.

Comment: You are still missing the distinction between compiling and running.  Only the *compiler* uses that file, you no doubt have an #import directive in your code.  When you *run* your program it will always use the 64-bit version of that COM server.

Comment: I see, and you're right, the path follows an #import command - but tell me please, it seems that I have to write the full path (starting with "C:\\..) for it to locate the file in the x64 directory. If the path begins with a "Common Files .." prefix it goes by default to the x86 directory .. can't I change it to go by default to the x64 directory instead ?